# Streaming data chunks of spawned process, properly in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, spawn

How can I stream data chunks of spawned process byte by byte?

When i try this

```
const spawned = spawn("cmd");

spawned.stdout.on("data", chunk => {
  const data = chunk.toString() as string;

  // code ...
  // code ...
  // code ...
});
```

It is printing every line but I want to get half lines too.

Like `Username:` or `Password:` 
So this is not a useful way for me. I have took a look to Stream documentation but I could not find the solution.

Comment: Your `data` object is already by default a `Buffer`, not a `String`, use the [Buffer API](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer).  You can get its length, read from it, etc... It is already bytes, not String, you are doing a `.toString()` to make a string out of it

Comment: What do you mean by "half lines" ? Please post an example of your desired output.

Comment: And about half lines:  you can easily after making a String, split it from a delimiter, or apply a regular expression on it

Comment: Currently every `chunk` is a line like "output string...\r\n", when there is an output like "output string" (without EOL) I am not able to get it from `on("data", ...)` event